# how to store edit text all values into single variable in customized layout in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am fetch the itemnames from database and append to the editext in customized listview. now i am change values in edittext i can print what i am printing i want store one variable

My code:

```
             public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editmainmenulist, null);
            holder.caption = (EditText) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.editmaimenu);
            holder.caption1=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.menuimage);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        //Fill EditText with the value you have in data source
        holder.caption.setText(itemnames[position]);
        holder.caption.setId(position);
        holder.caption1.setImageBitmap(bmps[position]);

        //we need to update adapter once we finish with editing
        holder.caption.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus){
                    final int position = v.getId();
                    final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                    itemnames[position] = Caption.getText().toString();
                    System.out.println(Caption.getText().toString());//here only i am printing all values i want store all values into one varible
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is hard to understand exactly what you mean. If you are getting data from a database you can use a custom CurorAdapter. The advantage is that if you use it you can access the data storred in the Cursor at any time. Another way to do it is by seting a tag with the desired data to your EditText. Please be more specific for further help.

Comment: i am getting from mysql database from server not sqlite

Answer (score 0):

You can use a declare String variable in you class scope and every time using system.out.println to print. So just below it append the new string to  string variable.

```
String str;//in the class scope

str = str.concat(Caption.getText().toString());//just below your 
system.out.print(str);
```

Try it

Answer (score 0):

create one static variable

```
static String str="";
str = str + Caption.getText().toString();
```

at last you will get all values in single string